# Document Version Alfresco Community 5.2

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-maven

I am new to Alfresco.
I have the following problem:
Retrieve the version of an Alfresco document (.docx). Display the version to the user. Allow the user to choose the
new version, then modify the Alfresco document by inserting the chosen version and persist the document.
How can I proceed? Have I use only Alfresco API or 3rd party libraries?
Thank you so much, Leo.

Comment: I am not completely sure what you are trying to do because the functionality you describe is available out-of-the-box with Share. You can see the version history. You can select an old version. You can rollback to any previous version.

Comment: I solved thank You very much. See the solution on the github of a developer in my group.

https://github.com/lucarautti/fip-document-version/blob/master/src/main/java/it/fip/CurrentVersion.java